# Can someone help me on the second part of this derivation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

**Pt.1**: A particle moves in one dimension under the action of a force F(v) per unit mass. Explain how you would compute the speed $v$ of the particle, and its position $x$,at time $t$.Suppose $F(v) =k(v_0+v)$, where $k$ and $v_0$ are two constants. Find $v(t)$ and $x(t)$ assuming that the particle starts from rest at the origin, i.e. $x(0) = 0,v(0) = 0$.

**Pt.2**: Suppose now that theforce is $F(x)$ instead of $F(v)$. Explain how would find the speed $v(x)$ at position $x$ and hence show that if the particle starts from rest at the origin $\frac{1}{2}v^2=\int_0^xF(x)dx$. Find $v(x)$ when $F(x) =k(x_0+x)$ and hence show that $x(t) =x_0[\cosh(\sqrt{kt})−1]$.

For the first half of the derivation I got $v=e^{et}$ and $x=\frac{e^{kt}-1}{k} + t$ but I have no clue how to do the second half or derivations like this. If someone could help that would be appreciated.

Comment: you  basically have to prove the work energy theorem

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit confused, could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: the total work is the change in kinetic energy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)#General_derivation_of_the_work%E2%80%93energy_theorem_for_a_particle

Comment: Your first derivation isn't correct either I think.

Comment: What is the first derivation meant to be? (Sorry I'm new at deriving equations and would appreciate the help)

Comment: I appreciate you're new to it but how then did you obtain a result in the first place? :-)

Comment: I set up the deq $\frac{dv}{dt} = k(v_0 + v)$ then I solved it using separation of variables, to get x I took the derivative of v

Answer (score 1):

1. Part 1:

$$F(v)=k(v_0+v)$$

Per unit of mass:

$$F=ma\Rightarrow k(v_0+v)=\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}t}$$
$$\frac{\text{d}v}{k(v_0+v)}=\text{d}t$$
Integrate between $(0,0)$ and $(t,v(t))$ to obtain $v(t)$:
$$\int_0^{v(t)}\frac{\text{d}v}{k(v_0+v)}=\int_0^t\text{d}t$$
Then:

$$v(t)=\frac{\text{d}x(t)}{\text{d}t}$$
Integrate between $(0,0)$ and $(t,x(t))$ to obtain $x(t)$.

2. Part 2:

$$F(x)=k(x_0+x)$$

Per unit of mass:

$$F=ma\Rightarrow k(x_0+x)=\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}t}$$
$$k(x_0+x)=\frac{\text{d}^2x}{\text{d}t^2}$$

Or slightly rewritten:

$$x''(t)-kx(t)=kx_0\tag{1}$$
$(1)$ is a second order, linear, non-homogeneous differential equation which solves easily to $x(t)$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the integration? From what I understand integrating within the same bounds, i.e. (0,0) just makes the integral 0.

Comment: Have a look now.

Comment: I see what I did wrong now for part 1, but I'm still confused on part 2 and how we're meant to solve for v(x) and x(t)

Comment: Firstly $x(t) =x_0[cosh(\sqrt{kt})−1]$ should really be $x(t) =x_0[\cosh(\sqrt{k}t)−1]$: the $t$ should not be under the square root.

Comment: But developing $(1)$ I get that same solution you claim for $x(t)$. Thanks for the upvote.